# Paypal form not displaying in Wordpress unless logged in as admin

Tags: html, wordpress, paypal

I'm having an issue with adding a Paypal form into a Wordpress website. The Paypal button and field won't show unless I'm logged in as an admin. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XBWSBD66AXMFW">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="...">...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="os0">
          <option value="1 Wristband">1 Wristband £7.50 GBP</option>
          <option value="2 Wristbands">2 Wristbands £15.00 GBP</option>
          <option value="3 Wristbands">3 Wristbands £22.50 GBP</option>
          <option value="4 Wristbands">4 Wristbands £30.00 GBP</option>
          <option value="5 Wristbands">5 Wristbands £37.50 GBP</option>
          <option value="6 Wristbands">6 Wristbands £45.00 GBP</option>
          <option value="7 Wristbands">7 Wristbands £52.50 GBP</option>
          <option value="8 Wristbands">8 Wristbands £60.00 GBP</option>
          <option value="9 Wristbands">9 Wristbands £67.50 GBP</option>
          <option value="10 Wristbands">10 Wristbands £75.00 GBP</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Are you using a caching plugin? If so, try flushing its cache and check again.

Comment: @cabrerahector - it had a lightspeed caching plugin installedd but i've deleted it and cleared cache but still no luck. The url is: https://greatbritishlrshow.com/tickets/ if that helps